# Rasa Core: utter_template() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tracker'

Tags: python, python-3.6, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am using Rasa core v10.2, with custom actions,  but getting `utter_template() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tracker'` error on the run function.

**Custom action file: (actions.py)**

```
from rasa_core.actions import Action
from rasa_core.events import SlotSet

class searchJob(Action):
    def name(self):
        return 'action_search'

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        return [SlotSet("jobsname", "as_aggregate")]
```

**domain.yml:**

```
slots:
  jobsname:
    type: text

templates:
 utter_answer:
    - text: "The required jobs are {jobsname}"
```

Stories:

```
* search
  - action_search
  - utter_answer
```

The output is `[{'recipient_id': 'default', 'text': 'The required jobs are None'}]` which means the Slot it not set. Could the error message be the cause of it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue seems to be the name of the custom action file, change it to anything else from 'actions' will do.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are looking at the right custom action? I had the same error message because in one of my custom action I was using `dispatcher.utter_template()` like this:

`dispatcher.utter_template('utter_something')`

and apparently `tracker` is now a required argument, i.e. I add `tracker` like this:

`dispatcher.utter_template('utter_something', tracker)`

and the error is gone.

PS: I know this should be a comment, but I am not allowed since my reputation is not high enough.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the issue in my case was the custom action file name.